# How to update the rows in parse.com using android platform if user reinstall the app or again open the app

Tags: android, parse-platform, storing-data

I have a problem with updating values per row in a cloud storage site called parse.com. I am only a newbie in using parse.com. I have read the documentation about it and have understood it, but what I want to do is a little bit different from the example there. Here's my code..

Please tell me where I am doing wrong to update the existing user if he installs the app again.

My code is:

```
ParseObject mayank = new ParseObject("Mayank");
mayank.put("UniqueId",androidId);
        mayank.put("EmailID",emailID);
        mayank.save();

ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Mayank");
query.whereEqualTo("UniqueId",androidId);
query.whereEqualTo("EmailID",emailID);
query.getInBackground(mayank.getObjectId(), new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(final ParseObject mayank, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    // Now let's update it with some new data.

                    mayank.put("EmailID",emailID);
                        mayank.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void done(ParseException e) {
                                if (e == null) {
                                    // Saved successfully.
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else {
                                    // The save failed.
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to Save", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "User update error: " + e);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

            }
        });
```

I want to update the email Id and app UniqueID that I have input. But as a result of my code, it creates a new row, instead of updating the existing row. What is lacking/wrong in my code?

Below is the screenshot what I am getting on the parse site, every time new row is added if the same person reinstall the app

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have fixed English issues with your post.  I have also removed the thanks, it is not necessary.  If you like the replies, you vote them up.

Comment: Ok sir and thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You should write a query to get the object from Parse DB at the first, then make your changes on it and save it. Problem is your `mayank` object does not have its `objectId`.

Also, `saveInBackground()` is not guarantee to save your object at the moment(even if internet connection is on). If you want to find your object after saving it into database, you should use `save()` method.

Change your first `saveInBackground()` with `save()`.

```
ParseObject mayank = new ParseObject("Mayank");
mayank.put("UniqueId",androidId);
mayank.put("EmailID",emailID);
mayank.save();

ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Mayank");

query.whereEqualTo("UniqueId",androidId);
query.whereEqualTo("EmailID",emailID);

query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                // Now let's update it with some new data.

                object.put("EmailID",emailID);
                object.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            // Saved successfully.
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            // The save failed.
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to Save", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "User update error: " + e);
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
});
```

---

Also note that: You should be careful about authenticate user without password, if you only use androidId and email(if default mobilephone authenticated email account there will no problem). Person, who bought somebody's phone, may login your application.

Comment: Can you please provide me a piece of code so that i will update my code. i  dont understand what you are saying. Please correct my code. Thanks

Comment: You should tell me which row you want to update. you should know unique data of row such as username, nick or objectId?

Comment: I am saving Unique ID and Email Id of the User but when user reinstall the app then again new row is added with the same information but if user is same then the row is updated not added and if user is different then new row will be added

Comment: rest of the code is correct or is there any correction required??

Comment: It seems correct, just add 'this' on updating and change first save in background with save.

Comment: I am getting Parse exception, no data found.. Please rewrite the code for me please just sample code .

Comment: objectid is null, so you should find your object with UniqueId and EmailID., answer updated!

Comment: this.mayank.put("EmailID",emailID) cannot be resolved. I have updated my answer and attached the screenshot also.

Comment: I removed 'final', try updated answer. I am sorry that I do not have computer and could not compile my code. If it does not work, I will help you in this evening :)

Comment: Ok i will try your code later but i want to ask one thing, if i reinstall the app then the row should be added or not ?

Comment: I depends on your business design. If users change their phone,  they can not access their account for your design, so you should get password also. If user android Id and "phone default account email(authenticated)" matches with your db object you should use it(do not create new row). If user changed its phone, you should access user info with email and request its password(do not create new row). If email does not match, then you should create new row for new user.

Answer (score 0):

Ohh its very simple way to update User Data Like this way to follow code style step by step.

**step 1.**

When user login that a time to store Comman Class user object.Like..

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> login = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Mayank");
    login.whereEqualTo("UniqueId", "yrandroidkey");
    login.whereEqualTo("EmailID", emailID);

    login.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {

        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject userobject, ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (e == null) {
                // Success
                // here store your user object as ParseObject in static
                // class
                // here i have store in comman class parseobject_user static
                // obj
                CommanClass.ParseObject_USER = userobject;
            } else {
                // Fail// e.getMessage()
            }
        }
    });
```

now user is login successfully in your application.
now u want to update his value after login application

**Step 2.**

```
// after user login u want to update his profile ..
    CommanClass.ParseObject_USER.put("EmailID", "test@gmail.com");

    CommanClass.ParseObject_USER.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {

        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (e == null) {
                // success

            } else {
                // fail
            }

        }
    });
```